# Why does CTRL+U clear everything with zsh, not only the text before cursor, as expected

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've installed zsh and oh-my-zsh on my Mac terminal, then CTRL+U cut everything I input, no matter where the cursor is.

If it's a common case, how can I set the CTRL+U to the original behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute, or most likely add it in your `~/.zshrc` to always have it:

```
bindkey "^U" backward-kill-line
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, also I find `bindkey` command (without any arguments) could list all hotkey in shell, which is very useful

Comment: Definitely worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This worked great but it's a bit weird that zsh would overwrite this standard `readline` behavior. Would be great if anyone can find a cause for this.